# Debug Assertion Failed: Vector subscript out of range

Tags: c++, debugging

Getting a failure alert that I unfortunately have no idea what it means. I tried to search other questions about debug assertion failures, but could not find anything that I understood as being the same issue that I have. It specifically states Line: 1501 Expression: Vector subscript out of range.
I have used vectors before and had no issues, can someone help explain what I am missing here?

Thank you

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    vector <int> someVec;
    vector <string> anotherVec;

    someVec.push_back(1);
    someVec.push_back(2);
    someVec.push_back(3);

    cout << "someVec size: " << someVec.size() << endl;

    anotherVec[0] = "Fred";
    anotherVec[1] = "Bob";
    anotherVec[2] = "Holly";

    anotherVec.push_back("John");

    for (int val : someVec)
    {
        cout << val << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;

    for (string name : anotherVec)
    {
        cout << name << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You never add any elements to `anotherVec` so you cannot access it using `[0]` (or any other index). You should use `push_back` just like you did for `someVec`

Comment: Thanks for the response, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
vector <string> anotherVec;
```

declares a vector of size 0. Then indexing into the vector like this:

```
anotherVec[0] = "Fred";
```

invokes undefined behavior. Instead, you can do:

```
anotherVec.push_back("Fred");
```

Or else, you can allocate enough space for the vector when you declare it, like this:

```
vector <string> anotherVec(3);
```

and then you can index into the vector with 0, 1, or 2.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you, I appreciate the help and the taking the time to really explain the logic behind what the issue was. There are a lot of little things that I don't realize will have an effect on the code, so I am really thankful for the response.

Comment: No problem, glad it helped :)